# NLTK BigramTagger erroring out on list(list(tuples()))

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

So I have a list which looks like this:

```
list[[tuple(),tuple(),tuple()], [tuple(),tuple(),tuple()]]
```

So basically a list of lists where each inner list contains tuples (word, tag).
When I try to train Bigram Tagger it returns me error

```
list := list[[tuple(),tuple(),tuple()], [tuple(),tuple(),tuple()]]
bigram_tagger = nltk.BigramTagger(list)
```

Return me error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PATH/project.py", line 123, in <module>
bigram_tagger = nltk.BigramTagger(list)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-   
packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 378, in __init__
backoff, cutoff, verbose)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 287, in __init__
self._train(train, cutoff, verbose)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 184, in _train
fd[context][tag] += 1
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: you have `list[...]` instead of `list(..)` or `[...]`, you need to pick one or the other.  Using both gives you an error but not `unhashable type`...

Comment: this is not a [Minimal Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  other then several syntax errors, I got a different error `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack` after changing `list : = list[...]` to `list = [...]`.  Please provide sufficient code to reproduce the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

May the naming convention error. Generally key words like 'list' should not be used for variable names.

That's why you may be getting this

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```